# Xamarin import of .so file successful but can't find the file's contents

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Output window prompts：

```
06-17 17:01:32.600 D/Mono    (14927): Searching for 'getcpufamily'.
06-17 17:01:32.600 D/Mono    (14927): Probing 'getcpufamily'.
06-17 17:01:32.600 D/Mono    (14927): Could not find 'getcpufamily' due to 'Could not find symbol 'getcpufamily'.'.
and :   06-17 17:01:32.776 W/Trace   (14927): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

my code is：

```
[DllImport("libcheckcpu.so")]
public static  extern int getcpufamily();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it of correct architecture? Did you define `ABI` for the .so file? Is it marked as `AndroidNativeLibrary`?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="path/to/libfoo.so">
        <Abi>armeabi</Abi>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
</ItemGroup>
```

Just in case here is the documentation:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/
Pretty sure you've seen it though.